# How to delete appended search elements in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have completed search with UISearchController. The search starts after typing 3 characters.

As you can see in following animated gif, after I delete search and start to type another search, device display previous search results.  These search results remains until I type 3 characters.

How can I clear previous search after delete or clear ?

```
if searchController.searchBar.text?.characters.count > 2 { ... }
```

[image]

Comment: where did you store the search result? Maybe you can try to clear that container if #chars is less than 3.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set searchController delegate to self , u can do so with Interface builder also and ignore

```
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
```

then call cancel button click handler and clean up your table

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
  
  // Clear any search criteria
  searchBar.text = ""
  
  // Dismiss the keyboard
  searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
  
  // Reload of table data
  //->> your search result table 
  self.searchResultTable.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Where do u save ur search results ? Which array ?  You have to do like myArray.removeAllObjects() before reloading your search results table

Comment: The problem is not related with cancel button.  Deleting search term and typing another one is the real case actually.

Comment: then where you check if text.length is more than 3 characters, add another check, if text.length is less than 3 characters you remove any search result were previously saved